# Finding logs for crashing application on Bluemix

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud

I have a node.js app that is crashing and have no idea why. When I try to access the logs for 'Files and Logs' in the app dashboard, it says 'The application is not started, so there are no files or logs available.'. I have no idea why my application is crashing and logs are not available!

**app.js**

```js
require('newrelic'); //monitoring

var express = require('express');//middleware
var app = express();

var cfenv = require('cfenv');// Cloud Foundry library
var appEnv = cfenv.getAppEnv();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.listen(appEnv.port, appEnv.bind, function() {
 console.log("server starting on " + appEnv.url);
});
```

applications:
- disk_quota: 1024M
  host: x
  name: x
  path: .
  domain: mybluemix.net
  instances: 1
  memory: 256M

Thanks for your help

**UPDATE**: All it took to fix this was upping my memory amount. The user agent for New Relic added some memory overhead that caused it to hit my 256MB limit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the logs for a crashed app, use this command:

`cf logs <appname> --recent`